# TransactionTooLargeException when trying to switch from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin, fragment

I have a Fragment attached to MainActivity. This Fragment has a RecyclerView whose Items are binded through an Adapter.

In the Adapter I listen on a click on an Item (row in recyclerView) and create an Intent to an Activity (YoutubePlayerActivity). When switching an TransactionTooLargeException occurs.

I just don´t know why this occurs...is a standard task that I want to switch from Fragment to an Activity. I´m not sending any Extras through the Intent. Just creating the Intent and saying startActivity() or startActivityFromFragment).

Any Ideas?

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context.activity, YoutubePlayerActivity::class.java)
                context.activity!!.startActivityFromFragment(context, Intent(context.activity, YoutubePlayerActivity::class.java), 876)
}
```

Error:

```
{
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4527596 bytes
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4154)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4527596 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:761)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:5155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4146)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace associated with your `TransactionTooLargeException`.

Comment: added the stack!

Comment: This looks like this is coming from `onSaveInstanceState()`. Check your activity and the fragments that it hosts and see what it is putting in that `Bundle`. 4,527,596 bytes is fairly large, so I would guess that you are putting a `Bitmap` in there.

Comment: When switching from a normal fragment to an activity it works...but because I am startingActivity(intent) from in an RecylerViewAdapter it is causing problems...any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with that issue?